# Compute the ratio between two columns using specified conditions

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a very simple problem here. I want to calculate the ratio between two columns in a dataframe. I want to calculate the ratio when column "COLD" is greater than zero. The ratio would be "COLE/COLD/3600". Another condition that I want to use is find the last value of "COLD" which is non zero and specify that ratio as zero.

The toy data is as follows:

```
new <- structure(list(DIST = c(290.5, 291.5, 292.5, 293.5, 294.5, 295.5, 
296.5, 297.5, 298.5, 299.5, 300.5, 301.5, 302.5, 303.5, 304.5, 
305.5, 306.5, 307.5, 308.5, 309.5), COLE = c(8.99599581870558e-34, 
4.7205846523432e-34, 2.46933986060826e-34, 1.28710593231168e-34, 
6.68129579857346e-35, 3.4504303472814e-35, 1.77184019853307e-35, 
9.05642991756649e-36, 4.6013156549926e-36, 2.31604511599026e-36, 
1.14687288574039e-36, 5.5010466649376e-37, 2.45427157311345e-37, 
8.97771568697138e-38, 2.3363639100918e-38, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0), COLD = c(6.1904901729067e-36, 
3.2185001604668e-36, 1.65347497008439e-36, 8.31494814855863e-37, 
4.01276411184216e-37, 1.77017459051552e-37, 5.41351248244182e-38, 
1.12878823222726e-38, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)), .Names = c("DIST", 
"COLE", "COLD"), class = "data.frame", row.names = 291:310)
```

The formula I used is as follows:

```
new$COLF <- ifelse(test=(new$COLD>0),(new$COLE/new$COLD/3600),0)
```

Can anyone suggest how can I automatically find the last row of the column "COLD" which is non-zero and then assign the value of "COLF" as zero ?

Thanks.

Comment: I've read it several times, but I still don't get what it is you want, that your `ifelse` construct doesn't do already.

Comment: `ifelse` only checks the "COLD" values that are greater than zero. It doesn't check the last non-zero value of "COLD". I need to assign the ratio to zero for the last non-zero value of "COLD"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
which.max(cumsum(abs(new$COLD) > 1e-100))
```

To find the index of the last non-zero `COLD`. Note that I used specific precision here - pick one that's appropriate for your data and use it in your other comparison as well, so do e.g. `new$COLD > -1e-100`. Comparing doubles should always involve some sort of a precision.

Comment: Or just `sum( new$COLD > 0)` ? Or  `sum( ! new$COLD == 0)` depending on if OP wants greater than zero (first paragraph) or non-zero (last paragraph!) values!

Comment: @SimonO101 - that will fail if you have zeros in between before the final ones

Comment: +1 for testing for edge cases, but this didn't appear to be an issue given the data posted

Comment: @ eddi and SimonO101 Thank you for your responses and the little conversation right there also helped to understand the limitations of the approaches suggested.

Comment: I find this a little more intuitive: `tail(which(abs(new$COLD) > 1e-100), 1)`